# removing entities in preUpdate event lister

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `preUpdate` listener for an Entity where I do some calculations, set values etc.

In that listener I would like to remove some other related entities, but this does not seem to be flushed by the entity manager. How can I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the Doctrine2 [docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/events.html#preupdate):

> Changes to associations of the updated entity are never allowed in
>   this event, since Doctrine cannot guarantee to correctly handle
>   referential integrity at this point of the flush operation.

Which means you shouldn't mess with the entities during the `preUpdate` event handling. I suggest you move your logic up to the service layer by using an entity manager. Write a specific method for updating your entitty and do all the complex stuff there. A nice example of an entity manager would be the FOSUserBundle's [`UserManager`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/v1.3.1/Doctrine/UserManager.php)

Comment: I've been searching around for this for hours and once I put the PreUpdate code into my service instead everything became easy. Thanks for this answer it is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you make a change to an entity in a `preUpdate` event listener you need to tell the unit of work to recompute that entity's changeset:

```
$em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
$cm = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));

$em->getUnitOfWork()->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($cm, $entity);
```

Comment: I'm doing that already. In addition to changes to the entity I am creating and deleting some other entities, and these creates and removes are not being flushed.