# Why isn't Symfony2 triggering my Doctrine event listener for `preUpdate`?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am attempting to add a simple Blowfish password encoder to Symfony2.

When a user model is updated with a new password then I need to trigger the password to be encoded before the model is persisted. I want to use the `preUpdate` Doctrine event tag in my `services.xml`.

Unfortunately it is not being triggered.

Oddly I am also subscribing to the `prePersist` event and that is being triggered correctly.

Is there some difference I am missing or some reason this does not work?

### services.xml

```
<service id="base.user.listener.persist" class="Base\UserBundle\Listener\PasswordEncoder">
    <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="preUpdate" />
    <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="prePersist" />
    <argument type="service" id="security.encoder.blowfish" />
</service>
```

### PasswordEncoder.php (event subscriber)

```
/**
 * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
 */
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $entity = $this->encodePassword($entity);
}

/**
 * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
 */
public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
    die('preUpdate');
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $entity = $this->encodePassword($entity);
}
```

If you need to see more code just sing out.

Comment: did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357855/preupdate-and-postupdate-events-not-triggered-on-doctrine-2 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931182/removing-entities-in-preupdate-event-lister

Comment: @ilanco first one yes, but it didn't apply as I am not using annotations in a model/entity (because it doesn't have access to the container or Blowfish encoder). Second one looks promising - thanks for linking it in. Although this still doesn't explain with the event is never triggered and the `die()` never gets displayed. Not being able to update entity is a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so there is nothing wrong with the `services.xml` definition. It seems that you must duplicate the subscription information in the listening class (`PasswordEncoder.php`) with:

```
public function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return array(
        Events::prePersist,
        Events::preUpdate,
    );
}
```